# How to calculate the following expectation? (related to F distribution)

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, expected-value

How to calculate the following expectation
$$
E\Big(\frac{m}{m + nF_{n,m}}\Big)^2
$$
where $F_{n, m}$ follows F-distribution.

Comment: Start with factoring out the constants. Is the denominator $(n+m)F_{n,m}$?

Comment: @callculus42 It should be $m+n F_{n, m}$